# Create a function that does not await, but calls a task inside it that does await

Tags: c#, .net

The normal async flow I have used thus far is

```
public Task<long> ListRightPushAsync(RedisKey key, RedisValue value, When when = When.Always, CommandFlags flags = CommandFlags.None)
{
      RecordUsage("ListRightPushAsync", key, ValueLength(value));
      return underlying.ListRightPushAsync(key, value, when, flags);
}
```

Doing some stuff, then we hit a point where something will block so instead of awaiting I return the async task from the function that blocks. In this case working with redis.

Now I have a use case where I want to use the value of that internal async, but not block with an await. So I tried this:

```
public Task<RedisValue> ListLeftPopAsync(RedisKey key, CommandFlags flags = CommandFlags.None)
    {
      Task<RedisValue> temp = new Task<long>(async () =>
      {
        RedisValue rv = await underlying.ListLeftPopAsync(key, flags);
        RecordUsage("ListLeftPopAsync", key, ValueLength(rv));
        return rv;
      });
      return temp;
    }
```

The goal is to record how much data came back from the async, but not block the root task so that the caller can await at the time of his choice. However this does not compile because the task does not want to be async. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `but not block with an await` - await specifically exists to not block. You appear to have been avoiding the intended way of using async all this time? When you `await`, it will return to your caller at that point. And your caller will be free to tuck your task away and await it later.

Comment: See https://dotnetfiddle.net/U5zHm4

Comment: Oh wow. you are right I wasn't thinking about it that way. Thanks!! I always was thinking of await as pop up to the very top and do other stuff and come back to me when done and in my mind the top was the very top but in this case its just the level above